# Web application using JSP,servlets and Struts

Tags: jsp, servlets, tags, struts

I'm developing a web application using JSP,Servlets and Struts.It has many dynamic web pages in some pages like login and other user details getting pages i used taglibrary tags with bean files,but in more complex pages i did'nt used taglib tags just i developed with java coding directly with AJAX coding.
Actually my question is how and where to use appropriate taglibrary TAGS? 
How to use AJAX and Java Script codes with library TAGS? 
What is the good idea to desing a good web application?

Answer (score 0):

You design your own tag when that view is repeatable and to reuse the view.

You  should import all js files in jsp and in jsp add tags.